# How to handle the meta description/keywords in a Zend Framework 2 application?

Tags: zend-framework2, keyword, meta-tags, head

The default page `title` defined in the layout file can be extended (`PREPEND`/`APPEND`) or replaced (`SET`) with a title specific for the current view.

Such behavior I've also been expecting for the [HeadMeta](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/HeadMeta.php) view helper. Now I cannot find any proper way to "extend" the default `descrition`/`keywords`, that I defined in the layout file.

Instead of it I can add a further `meta` tag with `append(...)`/`appendName(...)` (similary to adding style or script file with [HeadLink](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/HeadLink.php) or [HeadScript](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/HeadScript.php)). But it doesn't make sense for `descrition` and `keywords` `meta` tags.

Is there a recommended approach to handle this? How to handle the `description`/`keywords` `meta` tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick&dirty workaroud, I'm currently using (for a clean solution instead of an ugly workaround changes at the framework are needed):

**HeadMeta view helper**

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\View\Helper;

use stdClass;
use Zend\View;
use Zend\View\Exception;
use Zend\View\Helper\HeadMeta as ZendHeadMeta;
use Zend\View\Helper\Placeholder\Container\AbstractContainer;

class HeadMeta extends ZendHeadMeta {

    const DELIMITER = ' - ';

    /**
     * @see \Zend\View\Helper\HeadMeta::__invoke()
     */
    public function __invoke($content = null, $keyValue = null, $keyType = 'name', $modifiers = array(), $placement = AbstractContainer::APPEND) {
        parent::__invoke($content, $keyValue, $keyType, $modifiers, $placement);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see \Zend\View\Helper\HeadMeta::append()
     */
    public function append($value) {
        if ($value->name == 'description') {
            $this->updateDescription($value, AbstractContainer::APPEND);
        } else if ($value->name == 'keywords') {
            $this->updateKeywords($value, AbstractContainer::APPEND);
        } else {
            parent::append($value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see \Zend\View\Helper\HeadMeta::prepend()
     */
    public function prepend($value) {
        if ($value->name == 'description') {
            $this->updateDescription($value, AbstractContainer::PREPEND);
        } else if ($value->name == 'keywords') {
            $this->updateKeywords($value, AbstractContainer::PREPEND);
        } else {
            parent::prepend($value);
        }
    }

    // Not working correctly!
    // Can cause a
    // Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
    /**
     * @see \Zend\View\Helper\HeadMeta::set()
     */
    public function set($value) {
        if ($value->name == 'description') {
            $this->updateDescription($value, AbstractContainer::SET);
        } else if ($value->name == 'keywords') {
            $this->updateKeywords($value, AbstractContainer::SET);
        } else {
            parent::set($value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * If a description meta already exsists, extends it with $value->content,
     * else creates a new desctiprion meta.
     * @param \stdClass $value
     * @param string $position
     */
    public function updateDescription(\stdClass $value, $position = AbstractContainer::SET) {
        $descriptionExists = false;
        foreach ($this->getContainer() as $item) {
            if ($this->isDescription($item)) {
                switch ($position) {
                    case AbstractContainer::APPEND:
                        $descriptionString = implode(static::DELIMITER, array($item->content, $value->content));
                        break;
                    case AbstractContainer::PREPEND:
                        $descriptionString = implode(static::DELIMITER, array($value->content, $item->content));
                        break;
                    case AbstractContainer::SET:
                    default:
                        $descriptionString = $value->content;
                        break;
                }
                $item->content = $descriptionString;
                $descriptionExists = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$descriptionExists) {
            switch ($position) {
                case AbstractContainer::APPEND:
                    parent::append($value);
                    break;
                case AbstractContainer::PREPEND:
                    parent::prepend($value);
                    break;
                case AbstractContainer::SET:
                default:
                    parent::set($value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * If a keywords meta already exsists, extends it with $value->content,
     * else creates a new keywords meta.
     * @param \stdClass $value
     * @param string $position
     */
    public function updateKeywords(\stdClass $value, $position = AbstractContainer::SET) {
        $keywordsExists = false;
        foreach ($this->getContainer() as $item) {
            if ($this->isKeywords($item)) {
                switch ($position) {
                        case AbstractContainer::APPEND:
                            $keywordsString = implode(', ', array($item->content, $value->content));
                            break;
                        case AbstractContainer::PREPEND:
                            $keywordsString = implode(', ', array($value->content, $item->content));
                            break;
                        case AbstractContainer::SET:
                        default:
                            $keywordsString = $value->content;
                            break;
                }
                $item->content = $keywordsString;
                $keywordsExists = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$keywordsExists) {
            parent::append($value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return description meta text
     */
    public function getDescription() {
        $description = null;
        foreach ($this->getContainer() as $item) {
            if ($this->isKeywords($item)) {
                $description = $item->content;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $description;
    }

    /**
     * @return keywords meta text
     */
    public function getKeywords() {
        $keywords = null;
        foreach ($this->getContainer() as $item) {
            if ($this->isKeywords($item)) {
                $keywords = $item->content;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $keywords;
    }

    /**
     * Checks, whether the input $item is an approproate object for $this->container
     * and wheter it's a description object (its name is "description")
     * @param stdClass $item
     * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isDescription(stdClass $item) {
        if (!in_array($item->type, $this->typeKeys)) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'Invalid type "%s" provided for meta',
                $item->type
            ));
        }
        return $item->name == 'description';
    }

    /**
     * Checks, whether the input $item is an approproate object for $this->container
     * and wheter it's a keywords object (its name is "keywords")
     * @param stdClass $item
     * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isKeywords(stdClass $item) {
        if (!in_array($item->type, $this->typeKeys)) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'Invalid type "%s" provided for meta',
                $item->type
            ));
        }
        return $item->name == 'keywords';
    }

}
```

**/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml**

```
<?php
$this->headMeta()->appendName(
    'description',
    $this->translate('default description')
);
$this->headMeta()->appendName(
    'keywords',
    implode(', ', array(
        $this->translate('default keyword 1'),
        $this->translate('default keyword 2'),
        $this->translate('default keyword 3'),
    ))
);
echo $this->headMeta();
?>
```

**view script**

```
<?php
$this->headMeta()->setName('keywords', implode(
    ', ',
    array(
        $this->translate('view specific keyword 1'),
        $this->translate('view specific keyword 2'),
        $this->translate('view specific keyword 3'),
    )
));
$this->headMeta()->setName('description', 'view specific description');
?>
```

Comment: Your solution works charm but please add a little note that helper should be attached into module properly. For example following line should exist in module.config.php `'view_helpers' => array( 'invokables' => array( 'headMeta' => '\YourModule\View\Helper\HeadMeta' )`

Comment: Got it working! First I added @zeliboba comment (with a finishing parenthesis ;) but then got the error : _PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\\ServiceManager\\Exception\\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\\View\\HelperPluginManager::createFromInvokable: failed retrieving "headmeta(alias: headMeta)" via invokable class "MyModule\\View\\Helper\\HeadMeta"; class does not exist'_ - which was solved by generating a new classmap for the module with _./bin/classmap_generator.php_

Answer (score 2):

Linking to my answer here: [How to change meta tags in zend framework layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349413/how-to-change-meta-tags-in-zend-framework-layout/22251196#22251196)

Here's what worked for me. In the layout file you have to make sure that the meta tags are echoed. It's empty at the stage but you will be marking where the meta tags will be outputted. This only disadvantage with this method would be that there doesn't seem to be a way to have a default meta tag so you will have to add the meta tag in each view file.

**In the layout file**

```
<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
```

**In the view .phtml file**

```
$this->headMeta("test description text", "description");
```

Comment: The question is how to replace previously defined meta tag. In your example previously defined meta does not exist – so you give irrelevant answer.